# How to make suspend function of a mock to throw a checked exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

Is there any way to get an exception response when calling `suspended` function?

Here is my solution but this is not working as I expected.

```
private fun mockServiceResponse() = service.stub {
    onBlocking { loadMessages(Mockito.any() ?: createInstance()) }
        .thenThrow(SocketException::class.java)
}
```

The test fails with the following error message.

> Checked exception is invalid for this method!
> Invalid: java.net.SocketException
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:

will work if I replace `thenThrow(SocketException::class.java)}`
with `thenAnswer { throw SocketException() }`